# Как установить generic-pae ядро на Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu

Я новый пользователь Ubuntu и по-неопытности установил версию x86-x64 версию Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. 4Gb ОЗУ мне мало. Недавно узнал, что можно расширить это значение до 64Gb, если установить ядро generic-pae. Как это сделать?
Или как можно перенести Ubuntu на x64? Сохранив все свои данные?

Comment: Эээм? А откуда появится больше памяти?

Comment: Дополнительную плашку ОЗУ на 4Gb я добавил, он ее не видит

Comment: А биос-то её видит?

Comment: В биосе написано memory: 4096MB

Comment: Так у Вас дополнительная планка не работает. Либо она битая, либо несовместимость по таймингам, либо еще что-то.

Comment: А `pae` это разве не из мира 32 бит?

Comment: pae из мира 32 бита

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не так все понял и сейчас проверить версию системы введя в терминале команду uname -m 
Мне вывелось x86_64, что означает, что версия 64-битная и никаких плясок с ОЗУ не нужно проводить, потому что скорее всего битое гнездо для ОЗУ.